# int cin. Still Working How?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int cin;
    cin >> cin;
    cout << "cin" << cin;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program. I thought it should give an error. But it compiled and gave output as `cin0`. i.e. `cin+junkvalue`

**P.S.** I understand that `cin >> cin`, is a **bit shift operation** here. 
But My Question is why are we able to declare `int cin` here?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare any variable name at a different scope than some existing variable. `cin` is not a keyword or a reserved name, just an official name of the input stream. In fact, if you don't use `using namespace std;` in your code, you could do `std::cin >> cin;` and read an integer value from the standard input.  [Should add that even with `using namespace std;`, you can still use namespace qualifiers, so `std::cin >> cin;` would work "with" as well as "without" that statement - I meant rather that it's a bad habit to use `using namespace ...` in general, I prefer to just type the namespace wherever it is needed]

Obviously, doing these sort of things are generally a bad idea. But it's well defined and "works" as long as you know what you are doing and don't need both at the same time.

Comment: So in the code, to get the user input for variable cin, i should use what. ::cin>>cin, to get the input.

Comment: And i never use `using namespace std;` in my code. This was in a quiz, and i got confused on seeing this code to work.

Comment: There are several ways to make this "work" as "intended". And yes, it's well-defined, `cin` is not "special" in any way.

Comment: thanks for the help though